# Formik submission problem with asyncStorage in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, formik

I have two inputs components for a login with formik :

```
 <View>
      <TextField
        style={{color: 'white'}}
        label={label}
        tintColor={formikProps.touched[formikKey] && formikProps.errors[formikKey] ? 'red' : 'white'}
        onChangeText={e => formikProps.setFieldValue(formikKey, e)}
        onBlur={formikProps.handleBlur(formikKey)}
        {...rest}
      />
      <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>
        {formikProps.touched[formikKey] && formikProps.errors[formikKey]}
      </Text>
    </View> .
```

Then i have a form for my login with formik :

```
{formikProps => (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <HeaderWithLogo source={Logo.docaBlack} style={styles.header} />
            <View style={styles.subContainer}>
              <Animatable.View animation="slideInRight">
                <InputWithMessage
                  label="Email"
                  formikProps={formikProps}
                  formikKey="email"
                  value={formikProps.values.email || email}
                  placeholder="dukekaboum@example.com"
                  autoFocus
                />
              </Animatable.View>
              <Animatable.View animation="slideInRight" delay={800}>
                <InputWithMessage
                  label="Mot de passe"
                  formikProps={formikProps}
                  value={formikProps.values.password || password}
                  formikKey="password"
                  placeholder="mot de passe"
                  secureTextEntry
                />
```

I use asyncStorage to store email & password after a success login. 
When i reload my loginScreen , the value of my mail input & password input are set with the value of my storage BUT when i want to reLogin, yup and formik say to me there is no mail value and no pass value ....

Haw can use nicely, asyncStorage and formik ??

Answer (score 0):

ok , solved with : **enableReinitialize** before **intialValues**